# How can I burn the bootloader onto atmega328 (not atmega328p)?

Tags: atmega328, bootloader, arduinoisp

Hi I bought some atmega328 chips (not to be confused with atmega328p). They are very similar but the atmega328p chips are just more power efficient, so I've read. Anyways, my goal is to burn the arduino bootloader onto these chips so that I can make some breadboard arduinos. I used the arduino ISP sketch and hooked up everything like so ->

[image]

I was following instructions from the following link ->

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

However, when I press the Burn Bootloader button under Tools, it keeps telling me that it can't verify that my chip is an atmega328p. Well it is not atmega328p but everywhere online says it does not matter since they are the same architecture. The error also tells me that I can override by typing -F, but it doesn't tell me where to input this. I'm pretty sure that may fix the issue, but I am not sure where I'm supposed to put the -F.

Also I saw another post that was similar to this one but the answer said that the problem is the atmega328 chip itself. Is it even possible to add the bootloader to these chips??? Other sources said it is, but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: use MiniCore https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How can I burn the bootloader onto ATmega328 (not ATmega328*P*)?**

As Juarj commented, For a variety of standalone AVR microcontrollers you can add new "cores" to the Arduino IDE using it's board manager.

This provides the Arduino IDE with information about your specific chip and this means the IDE can instruct the `avrdude` program appropriately and select a bootloader image that was written to support your specific chip

The [Minicore documentation](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore#supported-microcontrollers) says it supports all variants of ATmega328

Other well-known examples of cores for bare AVR microcontroller chips  include [ATtinycore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) which supports a wide range of ATtiny microcontroller chips like the popular ATtiny85.

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I will definitely try this!